# How to load a certificate from "Credential storage"?

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, certificate, credentials

My network code is written in NDK (cURL + OpenSSL) and I'd like to use a certificate from Android's credential storage as a client certificate for a SSL connection. Moreover, I'd like to offer a list of available certificates to the user, so he can choose the certificate for the connection. Unfortunately, I cannot obtain a certificate from the key storage.

I installed a client certificate to "Credential storage" (Settings -> Secutrity -> ...) on my Android device (5.0.2), but I'm not able to access it from Java. I tried to call following code, but the key storage is empy, athough the certificate is installed in the Credential storage:

```
//KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
ks.load(null);

Enumeration<String> aliases = ks.aliases();
while(aliases.hasMoreElements()) {
    String alias = (String)aliases.nextElement();
    Log.i("app", "alias name: " + alias);
    Certificate certificate = ks.getCertificate(alias);
    Log.i("app", certificate.toString());
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User credentials installed on the device are available through Android [KeyChain](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/KeyChain.html), not Android [KeyStore](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore)

> The KeyChain class provides access to private keys and their corresponding certificate chains in credential storage.

Use `choosePrivateKeyAlias` ​​to prompt the user for selecting the certificate. The system launches an `Activity` for the user to select the alias and returns it via a callback. Then use `getPrivateKey` and `getCertificate` to recover the key and the corresponding certificate chain

```
KeyChain.choosePrivateKeyAlias(activity, new KeyChainAliasCallback() {
            public void alias(String alias) {               
                //do something with the selected alias                      
            }               
        },
        new String[] { KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA, "DSA"}, // List of acceptable key types. null for any
        null,                        // issuer, null for any
        null,                        // host name of server requesting the cert, null if unavailable
        -1,                          // port of server requesting the cert, -1 if unavailable
        "");                         // alias to preselect, null if unavailable
```

---

```
PrivateKey privateKey = KeyChain.getPrivateKey(activity, alias);
X509Certificate chain[] = KeyChain.getCertificateChain(activity, alias);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
X509TrustManager manager = null;
FileInputStream fs = null;

TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());

try
{
    fs = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore")); 
    keyStore.load(fs, null);
}
finally
{
    if (fs != null) { fs.close(); }
}

trustManagerFactory.init(keyStore);
TrustManager[] managers = trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers();

for (TrustManager tm : managers)
{
    if (tm instanceof X509TrustManager) 
    {
        manager = (X509TrustManager) tm;
        break;
    }
}
```